# Piping into a child process into another child process

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, system-calls

I am trying to create two pipes, the input of the first one is the contents of the input file in `argv[1]` of the parent process line by line, piped into a `mapper` process which does some work, and then finally into a `reducer` process which reduces it.

When I run my `mapper` and `reducer` like this in `bash:

```
./mapper < input.txt | reducer
```

It works perfect, but the following program outputs nothing and hangs on the `wait(NULL);`

**My Code**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void checkForkError(pid_t pid);
void mapperSetup(int mapperPipe[]);
void reducerSetup(int reducerPipe[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("please specify an input file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int mapperPipe[2]; //last index write end, first index read end

    if (pipe(mapperPipe) == -1) {
           perror("error piping");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t firstChild = fork();

    checkForkError(firstChild);

    if(firstChild == 0) { //child
        mapperSetup(mapperPipe);
    }
    else {
        close(mapperPipe[0]);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup(mapperPipe[1]);
        FILE* in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(in == NULL) {
            perror("error opening file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ssize_t read;
        size_t n;
        char* line = NULL;
        while(read = getline(&line, &n, in) != -1) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, line, n);
        }
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        free(line);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}

void inline checkForkError(pid_t pid) {
    if(pid < 0) {
        perror("error forking!!!");
    }
}

void mapperSetup(int mapperPipe[]) {
    int reducerPipe[2];

    if(pipe(reducerPipe) == -1) {
        perror("error piping");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t secondChild = fork();

    checkForkError(secondChild);
    if(secondChild == 0) { //reducer process
        reducerSetup(reducerPipe);
    }
    else { //mapper process
        close(mapperPipe[1]); //close write end
        close(STDIN_FILENO); //close stdin
        dup(mapperPipe[0]); //dup pipe out to stdin

        close(reducerPipe[0]); //close read end
        close(STDOUT_FILENO); //close stdout
        dup(reducerPipe[1]); //dup output to reducer pipe

        if(execv("mapper", (char *[]){"mapper", NULL}) == -1) {
            perror("exec error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void reducerSetup(int reducerPipe[]) {
    close(reducerPipe[1]); //close write end of second pipe
    close(STDIN_FILENO); //close stdin
    dup(reducerPipe[0]); //dup read end of pipe to stdin

    if(execv("reducer", (char *[]){"reducer", NULL}) != -1) {
        perror("exec error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: while(read = getline(&line, &n, in) != -1) ---> while((read = getline(&line, &n, in)) != -1)   Added parenthesis

Comment: nope that didnt change anything

Comment: In addition to the mistake terence called out, you should also be passing the variable 'read' to your write call, rather than 'n'.  'n' is the amount of space allocated, and is generally bigger than the actual amount read, causing some of the same data to be written repeatedly.  This is why you didn't see any change from terence's suggestion.  Those two changes have fixed the output for me, but I have not yet figured out your wait() problem.

Comment: Nice catch!  Unfortunately it doesnt fix the problem, the children dont seem to be doing anything after I call exec...but exec doesn't throw any errors either.

Comment: I replaced your mapper and reducer programs with /bin/cat, to simplify troubleshooting.  I am getting the input echoed out properly, but the first cat process is then hanging trying to read more data from the pipe (I am running strace to see the system calls).

Comment: that's odd shouldn't the EOF get sent when this program closes the pipe?

Comment: That's what I was expecting as well, yes.

Comment: aha! no because the reducer program still has those pipes open! i have to close them

Comment: Perhaps, but more importantly, the main process still has a copy of the pipe open, since you did a dup on it.  You closed the dup'ed copy, but not the original one.

Comment: no that's not how dup works, it simply duplicates the fd to the other fd number, close() operates on both of them the same

Comment: From the close manpage: "If  fd  is  the  last  file  descriptor  referring  to  the underlying open file description (see open(2)), the resources associated with the open file description are freed".  Also, I verified through /proc/<pid>/fd that the second copy was still open.

Comment: I just tried anyway and it fixed the issue, now im printing everything but just not exiting, a tad closer.  I didn't realize dup added a reference count ot the filedescriptor table since it's the same process

Comment: I suspect you still have something not closed.  My copy exits now.  You can troubleshoot it by looking at all three processes under /proc/<pid>/fd.  For example if the process IDs were 6000, 6001, and 6002: ls -l /proc/6000/fd; ls -l /proc/6001/fd; ls -l /proc/6002/fd

Comment: yeah im doing that, the fd's are still there even if they arent closed though, when they're highlighted red means they closed?  I dont like relying on highlights

Comment: No, I think the highlights are just different types of files.  The entries disappear from the fd directory when the file descriptors are closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100813/discussion-between-russell-reed-and-brandon-ross-pollack).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you have multiple `fd's` after a `dup` you must close the original as well as the new `dup` when you're done for the `EOF` to be sent.

In short, the `FD` references count is incremented for a `dup`.

The other problem is that my process tree is linear, not two children of one process, so the main process exits before the output, causing bash to have outputs after the execution seems to finish, making it look like it was hanging when it wasnt.

The solution is to create both pipes and forks from the parent process with a little restructuring.

Special thanks to Russell Reed who helped me out.